# 達 返 遠 速 What are these kanji characters sitting on?

Tags: kanji

達 返 遠 速 All these kanji seem to be set on a shoe, or a boat, or something. What is it called? Does it mean something?

Comment: @aguijonazo What do you mean by that? Aren't they just asking what ⻌ means, but didn't know how to refer to it?

Comment: @Leebo - Oh, then I didn’t get the question right. I didn’t think anyone would refer to that thing as a shoe or a boat. Now that I think about it, it looks more like a kickboard or something.

Comment: I always liked to say it was a platform, but I like boat better. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called しんにょう or しんにゅう. It means something to do with roads/ways/walking. (Your examples mean *reach/return/far/fast* respectively).

The modern norm is one dot at the first (top left) stroke (= total three strokes), but it used to be two dots like the following picture; and today non regular kanjis (outside 常用漢字) has still two dots. See the references below for details.

[image: dbk]
[image: tuji]

**References**

- [Wikipedia/繞#しんにょう](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B9%9E#%E3%81%97%E3%82%93%E3%81%AB%E3%82%87%E3%81%86)
- [「つじ」の「しんにょう」は１点？　２点？](https://mainichi-kotoba.jp/blog-20171223)
- [第228回 越後と「辶」（しんにょう）](https://dictionary.sanseido-publ.co.jp/column/kanji_genzai228)
- [部首：しんにょう・しんにゅう（辵 辶）の漢字（画数順）](https://kanji.jitenon.jp/cat/bushu03015.html)

Comment: FWIW, the "modern" one as you say is 3 strokes; the older one is 4.  Though most people write them as 2 and 3 respectively.  So for those that are looking up kanji by stroke count, keep that in mind.

Comment: Additional detail: the radical forms ⻍, ⻌ are simplifications of older character [辵](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%BE%B5#Chinese), in turn a combination of 彳 (“walk”, half of 行) + 止 (“foot” or “to stop”).

Comment: @istrasci Thanks, I meant for the first dot alone. I added pictures.

Comment: @sundowner:  No, I knew what you meant.  I was just clarifying the whole radical for those that might not have known.